# Jmeter Image Base64 post by Preprocessor

Tags: json, image, jmeter, base64, load-testing

I have a following csv

```
FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,ImageLocation
Jack|Michel|Rechards|D:\Image\picture.jpg
```

And I am using JSR223 Preprocessor to prepare my json

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def json = new JsonBuilder()
json {
    myData {
        firstName vars.get("FirstName")
        MiddleName vars.get("MiddleName")
        LastName vars.get("LastName")
        //How to handle Image base 64 for post ?
    }
}
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",json.toPrettyString(),"")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

My expected json would be like below

```
{
    "myData": {
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "MiddleName": "Michel",
        "LastName": "Rechards",
        "Image": Base64 Image Data
    }
}
```

How can I take image from file location and convert it to base64 and post it?
Using Beanshell Preprocessor would be good for me instead of JSR223 Preprocessor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
def imageStream = IOUtils.toByteArray(new URL("file:///D:/Image/picture.jpg"))
def imageBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageStream)
```

Full code just in case:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def imageStream = IOUtils.toByteArray(new URL("file:///D:/Image/picture.jpg"))
def imageBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageStream)



def json = new JsonBuilder()
json {
    myData {
        "firstName" vars.get("FirstName")
        "MiddleName" vars.get("MiddleName")
        "LastName" vars.get("LastName")
        "Image" imageBase64
    }
}

sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",json.toPrettyString(),"")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

References:

- [IOUtils JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)
- [Base64 JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)